# Computing areas of influence using QGIS

Tags: qgis, routing, proximity, qgis-network-analysis

I am trying to create a polygon layer showing polygons that correspond to a closest store.

For a set of 30 store locations, the result should be a polygon layer with 30 features, one for each store. Each feature will represent an area where it's corresponding store is the closest. For example, an address within polygon 12 means that store 12 is the closest.

I have my store locations layer and OSM streets layer with max speed column. The resulting polygon layer should be based on the OSM streets layer and not simply linear areas.

The idea is that given a fixed set of stores and roads, the closest store should remain constant at any given point on a map. Thus, I am hoping that the resulting polygon layer will be gapless.

[This](http://www.caliper.com/video/maptitude/maptitude-areas-of-influence-video/maptitude-areas-of-influence-video.html) video of Maptitude software provides a perfect example of what I'm trying to accomplish (fast forward to 1:55 of the video). Alternatively, see the image below for an example:

[image: Maptitude Areas Closest to Hospital]

For each hospital, there is a corresponding area where anything within that area is closest to the hospital located within that area.

How can I replicate this using QGIS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the grass algorithm [**v.net.alloc**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.net.alloc.html) can produce the subnets - you can call it from the Processing toolbox (tested in QGIS 2.16)

You'll need a point layer (for facilities) and a lines layer with costs (either time/length). It'll create a new line layer with a field called `cat` added, which will be the id of the nearest facility.

Here's an example based on walking distance to the nearest pub. Each line segment is coloured by `cat` using random colours:-

[image: v.net.alloc example]

Note that sometimes two adjacent pubs' road networks are given very similar colours; if you label them, you'll see it has actually worked.

As to getting gap-free polygons like you show above, I'm stumped. If you 'extract nodes' on the results and apply 'Convex Hull' (grouping by cat), there will be gaps and overlaps.

---

you can indeed get the desired result. As you suggested in your comment, you can do the following..

- run **Extract nodes** on the output of v.net.alloc
- run **Voronoi polygons** on the extract nodes layer
- run **Fixed distance buffer** on that to make sure polygons overlap (e.g  buffer by 1 meter)
- run **Dissolve** on the buffered layer, using the field 'cat'

Here's the result...it's not perfect, you'll sometimes see parts of the road network stray into neighbouring polygons.

[image]

There's a 'trap' in the new 2.16 GUI for dissolve. I set the field, but it seemed to dissolve everything. You need to remember to uncheck the 'dissolve all' checkbox, or the field setting is ignored.

Comment: This is helpful and I can certainly use the result in my application. I will leave this open temporarily to see if there's a way to end up with polygons. Is it possible that using the Voroni Polygons tool somehow would help?

Comment: a Voronoi on your facilities will only give an approximation, based on Euclidian distance ["as the crow flies"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_the_crow_flies), so it effectively ignores your road network.

Comment: I'm curious if I were to extract nodes on the v.net.alloc result, voroni that, and then dissolve the voting polygons based on the unique facility identifier. The size of the roads dataset is very large so I won't be able to test this quickly, but maybe in the meantime there will be some thoughts as to why this may not work out.

Comment: actually, your hunch is right - just tried it.

Comment: have updated answer with example

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just wondering, how did you get that shadow effect on the inside of the polygons?

Comment: that's 'draw effects', with 'inner glow' (using black rather than the default white)

Comment: OK great...although I trust your answer, I will confirm that it works on my end and then mark it as correct(unfortunately won't be for a few days)

Comment: Everything has worked so far up until Voronoi Polygons. It has been running for quite some time now. My input file has about 2.2 million nodes, which could be the issue. Voronoi is just stuck at 99% but I can see the processer is working. Will this ever stop running? Maybe my input file contains too many nodes?

Comment: This ended up working, but I feel there should be a more efficient way to get the result. 20 hours to make Voronoi polygons for 2.2 million points, then another 12 for the dissolves. I noticed Voronoi only generated 1.8 million polygons, which I suspect is because of overlapping nodes where roads meet. Also, I had issues clipping the dissolved Voronoi polygons; I had to run v.clean before they would clip properly. Lastly, it'd be nice to take road direction into account with this too but I'm not sure how. Anyways, thanks for all the help and testing!

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: There's a few nuisances with this workflow that I've figured out how to overcome. Fixed distance buffer tool is not necessary. The SAGA `Dissolve` tool seems to be much faster than the QGIS equivalent. And, it also seems quicker to split the `Voronoi` layer by `cat` field, and then `dissolve` each area separately. `Merge` them back together. Then, run GRASS `v.clean` and choose the tool `rmdupl` to remove duplicate nodes. This is important otherwise other processes like clipping, spatial joining, all will not work properly on the merged dissolved voronoi lauyer.

Comment: Yet another update: Don't use `rmdupl`, you must remove overlapping nodes instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a repository I created to automate this, liberating all of the nuances buried in the answers comments: https://github.com/mattmarotta/QGIS-Subnet-Areas

I will leave the current answer as is, largely due to the contributions of @Steven Kay (many thanks!)