# Coloring service area using QGIS and GRASS tool v.net.alloc

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network-analyst

I try to work with v.net.alloc to find some service area for my problem in QGIS 2.18.13.
That algorithm work nice create categories from my roads for any hotspot like this :

[image: n.net.alloc]

and if use style categories then I have a simple coloring road map for any hotspot.

My question is how to coloring all service area and not only the service road like this example :

[image]

I need with the some method to coloring all area from service area using v.net.alloc.

any idea ?

Comment: did you try the contour plugin ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/209419/55203)? I thought I recognised that second image :)

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup how to use contour plugin  in this case ?

Comment: @Steven Kay images is simple examples

Comment: @underdark I don't have code yet